# Angular Material touch screen scrolling issues

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have several places in my Angular Material application that do not seem to scroll on mobile touchscreen devices. Mat-buttons seem to be the issue but not in every case.

- For example, I have a responsive button component that does not
  scroll horizontally on mobile. The scroll bar shows, but the buttons
  won't allow touch scrolling.
- This is the same on my mat-tables. I have a column for CRUD
  operations that use mat-icon-buttons. This is the only part of the
  table that will not allow scrolling when the user's touch it.
- My main SideNav also does not scroll vertically when collapsed. I
  collapse it down to a list of mat-list-items with mat-icons.

It is weird because anytime I create a new project or stackblitz to recreate this effect, it does not happen.

Here is a dumbed down version of my responsive button component with the same html and css structure: [Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-8-starter). If you use your browser's built in responsive viewer it should scroll just fine.

I have even copied the exact code from that blitz into my application and it does not work properly. It just refuses to scroll on touch no matter where I put it / what I change.

If I remove the mat-*******-button from the buttons in my app, everything works as expected. It seems to be an issue with certain directives maybe?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would work in any material version ...
in your `styles.css`

```
.mat-tooltip-trigger {
  touch-action: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For anyone else experiencing this issue, track it here: [Issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4892)

After lots and lots of trial and error I found that mat-tooltips are to blame for this behavior. Apparently this has been a serious issue since mid-2017. Removing them solves the problem, but that is not really a proper fix. There is a work around posted in the issue on GitHub I am going to try out.

EDIT:

I could not get the workaround solution to work. Leave a comment on this answer or the GitHub thread if an alternative is found.

Comment: This workaround worked for me on angular 8.2:

`[mattooltip], [mattooltipposition] {  touch-action: auto !important; }`

For some reason the `mattoolip` attribute didn't exist on the elements the tooltip was applied to.

Comment: [mattooltip], [mattooltipposition] { touch-action: auto !important; } does not work for me (angular 8.3.24, material 8.2.3).

Comment: Nothing in this answer/comment-section worked, but the answer above by @Belal Aglan worked on ng v14. I would make that the correct answer.